# What happened to the AT-TEs after the rise of the Galactic Empire?

Tags: star-wars

During the Clone Wars, the Republic is seen using many vehicles, ships and weapons which do not feature in the armies and fleets of the Empire, despite the fact that the Republic transformed into the Galactic Empire (meaning that the Empire would have full control of these weapons).

I understand that the majority of the Republic's navy (especially the Venator/Victory class) were initially absorbed and gradually phased out of the Imperial fleet. However the saga seems to remain silent on the fate of the [AT-TE](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Tactical_Enforcer)s (All Terrain Tactical Enforcers).

Comment: I would guess they were replaced by the AT-STs and AT-ATs, depending on the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wookieepedia covers this in detail on the "[Imperial use](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Tactical_Enforcer#Imperial_use)" section of AT-TE Article

> During the Galactic Civil War, surviving AT-TEs were still used by the Empire, mainly in campaigns in the Outer Rim Territories.(Source: *The New Essential Guide to Vehicles and Vessels)
>
> The walkers no longer held a primary status in military campaigns, but were sometimes used for additional fire-support alongside larger assault vehicles, including AT-AT walkers and Juggernaut tanks. (source: *Star Wars: Rebellion: My Brother, My Enemy*)

Answer (score 0):

One AT-TE was acquired by a trio of clone who didn't execute Order 66. It was used as a mobile home before being destroyed on the planet Seelos. Other AT-TEs were used by the Rebel Alliance in the fight against the Empire.

Comment: It would help if you explained your source(s) behind these statements.